# Certificate installation error on mono 4.1.0

Tags: mono, dnx

I want to run aspnet 5.0 on Linux with latest build of Mono. I was able to successfully install mono 4.1.0 from github/master. When I tried to install the certificates, I get the below error

[image]

In case the image is not clear the error says

```
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
```

Anybody facing this issue and have a solution? I cannot continue installation of aspnet packages unless this is fixed and I wasn't able to get any solution from my online searches. Additional info, when i run 'sudo mozroots --import --sync' I get the error

```
sudo mozroots --import --sync
Mozilla Roots Importer - version 4.1.0.0
Download and import trusted root certificates from Mozilla's MXR.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

Downloading from 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1'...
Couldn't retrieve the file using the supplied information.
```

Comment: I'm also having this problem but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: @jdasilva: I have opened a bug on bugzilla and hopefully can hear from somebody on the mono team

Comment: @SuhasJoshi, what's the bug id/link?

Answer (score 5):

Seems `mozroots` is your problem. As a workaround you can do this:

```
 wget -q 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1' -O "/tmp/certdata.txt" 
 mozroots --import --ask-remove --file /tmp/certdata.txt
```

The full story could be found here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1279952#c8

And the better [suggestion](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/f094041420e5a7c5e00b12b78a904503629cb484/mcs/tools/security/mozroots.cs#L292) is

```
Console.WriteLine ("WARNING: mozroots is deprecated, please move to cert-sync instead.");
```